# Is the value of a string between two other strings?

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to create a function that will allow me to tell if the VALUE of a string (lexicographical) is between two other strings.  Can anyone check it out and let me know where I have gone wrong?  please keep in mind I am relatively new to C#.

```
    public static bool WithinRange(string pstrLowEnd, string pstrHighEnd, string pstrNum)
    {
        bool lbInclusive = false;

        if (pstrLowEnd <= pstrNum && pstrNum <= pstrHighEnd)
        {
            lbInclusive = true;
        }  

        return lbInclusive;
    }
```

The error being generated is that <= and => cannot be applied to string and string.  I am hoping there is an easy fix, but I just don't have it in my knowledgebank as of yet.

Thank you!

Comment: the strings contain numbers?

Comment: I don't understand this. Can you give examples of which parameter values should return true and which should return false?

Comment: they may... for example lowEnd might be 333 and highEnd might be 333ZZ.   if the number in question was 333AB it should be true where 343AB would be false

Comment: @Gazrok can you give at least one input sample, expected output, and the actual results you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `string.CompareTo()`, this method returns a signed integer that indicates the lexical relationship between the two strings:

```
public static bool WithinRange(string pstrLowEnd, string pstrHighEnd, string pstrNum)
{
    bool lbInclusive = false;

    if (pstrNum.CompareTo(pstrLowEnd) >= 0 && pstrNum.CompareTo(pstrHighEnd) <= 0)
    {
        lbInclusive = true;
    }

    return lbInclusive;
}
```

Or just:

```
return pstrNum.CompareTo(pstrLowEnd) >= 0 && pstrNum.CompareTo(pstrHighEnd) <= 0;
```

Comment: To understand the magic vodoo https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `a < b` with `string.Compare(a,b)==-1` for strings and it should compile (`<=` becomes `compare <= 0`).